# How to specify the folder on remote machine for backup usinf thinBackup plugin of jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to take the backup of jenkins confuguration in case if I lode my machine. I am using the **thinBackup** plugin provided by jenkins. It has an  option where I provide the path to folder where I want to take the backup.
Now the problem is I want to specify the folder on another machine, as it makes sense to have backup on different machine, how do I specifythe path to that folder? Do I have to specify as if

`abc@12.34.567.890:path/to/folder`?

I am new to jenkins so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thin backup performs just copies of jenkins configuration files in a specific folder for convenience. Is up to you to store it to scm or other machines, but it can be done with some simple script that upload your backup zip if exists

Comment: How do I store it to scm automatically? or Can you help me understand how do I write that script? Answer to any of these will help me move forward.

Comment: For some strange reason when I use the scm sync config plugin, it always says, Unable to access the repository. I tried providing it my svn credentials. Then the passing the certificate. Still I was unable to perform the required specification. Can you help regarding this?

Comment: Some months ago I've found issues from people that asked thinbackup maintainers to provide some hook that could trigger action after backup completion. Too bad there's nothing else about it. The only thing that came to my mind was to create a freestyle job configured with a periodic build trigger that manage the backups (in my case, uploading them to my cloud provider's storage service).  With freestyle jobs you can make http requests or execute  bat/sh scripts. just schedule it some minutes after the backup schedule. Is the less inelegant thing that you can do with these tools

Comment: Thanks. Now what I do is I push the backup to my svn directories externally. Your help allowed me to take the decision. So I am marking your answer as correct. Thanks once again.